# Conditional Formatting based on percentage formula

Tags: excel, vba

Please help to highlight cells which are above 5% of average, I thank all of you as this has given me nightmares as I can not make it work.

I have a range of cells, from F5 to AX5, with an average in cell AZ5, I just want to highlight any cells which are above 5% of the average value which is in cel AZ5. Here's what I've tried:

```
Sub test()

'Definining the variables:
Dim rng As String
Dim condition1 As FormatCondition
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sheetID As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' the excel workbook that contains the vba code

'Define what sheet to use
sheetID = "Summary"

'Fixing/Setting the range on which conditional formatting is to be desired
rng = "F5:AX5"


With wb.Sheets(sheetID).Range(rng)

    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AZ5>5%"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = 0.599963377788629
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False


End Sub
```

Even this simple version made by the macro won't work:

```
Sub Macro1()
    
    Range("F5:AX5").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
        Formula1:="=AZ5>5%"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What happens when you run your version? How do we reproduce your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, when I press F5 to run the code, nothing happens. I tried the code below, it kinda works, but only highlights the first cell:

Comment: Sub Macro3()
    
    Range("F5:AX5").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AZ5>5%"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    
End Sub

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in it so you can step through it?

Comment: I press F8 line by line, nothing happens at all

Comment: Where is your code in VBProject?

Comment: `Formula1:="=$AZ5>5%"`

Comment: Thank you Spectral,but it had no effect either

Comment: Dear Black Cat, I have no idea of VBProject

Answer (score 0):

The cod will simple check if value in each cell for the given range is more than 105 % (Means 5% additional to AZ5)

Hope it helps

```
   Sub HighlightCells()
        Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In Range("F5:AX5")
            If cell.Value > Range("AZ5").Value * 1.05 Then
                cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'Change the color to yellow
            End If
        Next cell
    End Sub
```

Comment: What did you change and why does it solve the issue?

Comment: Very simple brother vba doesnt work with percentage sign.. so here is the change"=AZ5>5/100", please accept it as answer

Comment: That's both not true and also makes no sense why it would work only for the first cell as the OP says.

Comment: Did you use it? Please share the result to check, it is working for me, working for first cell as it stops at first probably, check using step by step u will get to know. Did u put a minus?

Comment: Hello Kadam, unfortunately it does not work

Comment: In office right now, will definitely check back and get back to u bro

Comment: HI, please check now and confirm if works or not

Comment: I recommend that you don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, will keep the same in mind.